# How to add a new layout and page template that is SXA compatible?

Tags: sxa

I created a new layout and page template and would like it to work with SXA in Experience Editor.
I needed to add the following to get it to render any components with rendering variants:

```
<experienceAccelerator>
  <renderingVariants>
    <allowedTemplates>
      <template name="Modal">{881F54C1-D532-458D-9376-A7AD21851AAB}</template>
    </allowedTemplates>
  </renderingVariants>
  <localDatasources>
    <pageRelativeLocationAllowedTemplates>
      <template name="Modal">{881F54C1-D532-458D-9376-A7AD21851AAB}</template>
    </pageRelativeLocationAllowedTemplates>
  </localDatasources>
</experienceAccelerator>
```

However two last issues, one is when adding a `Container` component I get this error:

```
Exception: System.ArgumentNullException
Message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: url
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String argumentName)
   at Sitecore.Text.UrlString..ctor(String url)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Grid.Pipelines.ExecutePageEditorAction.FillGridDefaultValues.GetTargetParameters(IInsertRenderingArgs args)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Grid.Pipelines.ExecutePageEditorAction.FillGridDefaultValues.Process(PipelineArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.ExecutePageEditorAction.ExecutePageEditorActionPipeline.Run(ExecutePageEditorActionArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Palette.OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

The other issue is that the SXA toolbox doesn't show.

## Edit:

I'm on SXA 10.0

Thanks to pete I have added this config too

```
  <mvc>
    <hiddenPlaceholders>
      <layout id="{D6234A91-C8BD-45FC-8184-6B573AE1D651}">
        <placeholder name="head"/>
        <placeholder name="body-bottom"/>
        <placeholder name="body-top"/>
      </layout>
    </hiddenPlaceholders>
  </mvc>
```

Here's my layout:

```
@model Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel
@{ 
    AssetLinks assetLinks = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="@Model.Item.Language.Name">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    @if (Html.Sxa().IsEdit)
    {
        assetLinks = AssetLinksGenerator.GenerateLinks(new ThemesProvider());
        foreach (string style in assetLinks.Styles)
        {
            @Html.Raw(style)
        }
    }
    @Html.Sxa().VisitorIdentification()
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
    @Html.Sxa().Placeholder("head")
</head>
<body @Html.Sxa().Body().Decorate()>
    @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("body-top")
    @Html.Sxa().GridBody()
    @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("body-bottom")
    @if (Html.Sxa().IsEdit)
    {
        foreach (string script in assetLinks.Scripts)
        {
            @Html.Raw(script)
        }
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks to Miguel Minoldo to get the toolbox working, but still getting the same error, only on the "main" placeholder, and only on the container. I am not adding a new Device, and the grid mapping in the Settings item is correct.

My main goal here is to have a layout that doesn't render any scripts or styles when not in edit mode.

Comment: Check also this handy blog post of mine when creating new layouts in SXA -> https://tothecore.sk/2019/05/13/hiding-body-top-and-other-placeholders-in-your-custom-mvc-layouts-with-sxa/

Comment: @PeterProcházka Thanks, a bit helpful, but this looks like it has changed in SXA 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SXA has some code that will copy the grid rendering parameters from the previous rendering on the placeholder that you are trying to add the component to.

In this case I had a rendering on the "main" placeholder that does not have any grid rendering parameters field.

This code is in `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Grid.Pipelines.ExecutePageEditorAction.FillGridDefaultValues`

```
protected virtual string GetTargetParameters(IInsertRenderingArgs args)
{
List<RenderingDefinition> placeholderRenderings = this.GetPlaceholderRenderings(args.Device, args.PlaceholderKey);
return placeholderRenderings.Count > 0 && args.Position < placeholderRenderings.Count ? new UrlString(placeholderRenderings.ElementAt<RenderingDefinition>(args.Position).Parameters).Parameters["GridParameters"] : string.Empty;
}
```

We can see here that it is doing a null check for whether the previous rendering has "GridParameters", but then it is not possible to create a new UrlString() with an empty string.

The workaround here is to not add any renderings to the placeholder that don't have have a grid rendering parameters field.

I have reported to Sitecore Support and it has been registered as a Wish with Reference Number 470566.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have a valid grid mapping selected:

[image: Grid Mapping Settings]

Also, for the missing SXA toolbox, make sure you have the `<div id="wrapper">` in your layout.

I hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks, you helped get the toolbox working, but the grid mapping is already correct